# Getting variable from class function

Tags: php

Is there a way to get variable that is set inside object's function after using that function?
in my case $season array

```
    class Patch{

       public function display(){

                $season = array(); //Variable for line chart 

       }
    }

$Patch = new Patch();
$Patch->display();
var_dump($Patch->$season());
```

Comment: If you make `$season` a public property of the class.

Comment: `$this->season = array();`

Comment: You might also want to look at this PHP Object Oriented Tutorial: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bH5s3/0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$season` exists *only* inside the scope of the `display` function.  If you want to access it via `$Patch->season`, then you'll need to declare it as `public` property of the class.

```
class Patch{
    public $season;

    public function display(){
        $this->season = array(); //Variable for line chart 
    }
}

$Patch = new Patch();
$Patch->display();
var_dump($Patch->season);
```

Answer (score 1):

make variable $season public visible

```
class Patch {
   public $season = array();
...
```

Comment: This won't work by itself, you'll still need to set the class variable from within the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are plenty of ways.

1 Declare variable as class property(best way)

```
 class Patch
 {
      private $season;

      public function getSeason () {
           return $this->season;
      }

      public function setSeason ($season) {
           $this->season = $season;
      }

      public function display () {
           echo $this->getSeason();
      }
 }

 $obj = new Patch();
 $obj->setSeason(array());
 $obj->display();
```

2. Return variable by method `display()` (also good but in some cases)
3. Pass variable via reference.

These are only some of methods.